# How can I fetch the whole cloudwatch logs with parsing?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I know 2 methods to extract cloudwatch log but none of them cover both whole and parsing:

- method 1 (limitation: I can't get the whole logs since limitation is 10000 and doesn't cover paginating):

```
query_string = f"parse @message \"[*] - * - *\" as eventTS, eventType, eventMessage"


# initialize CloudWatch Logs client
client = boto3.client(
    service_name='logs',
    region_name=aws_region,
    aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key
)

# start log query
start_query_response = client.start_query(
    logGroupName=log_group_name,
    startTime=start_time,
    endTime=end_time,
    queryString=query_string,
)

# get queryId
query_id = start_query_response['queryId']


# wait for query result
while True:
    response = client.get_query_results(queryId=query_id)

    if response['status'] == 'Running':
        time.sleep(5)
    elif response['status'] == 'Complete':
        break
    else:
        print("error")
        raise
len_rows = 0
if response['status'] == 'Complete':
    for item in response['results']:
        row = {}

        for event in item:
            key = event['field']
            value = event['value']
            if key != '@ptr':
                row[key] = value

        print(row)
        print()
        len_rows += 1
```

- method 2 (limitation: doesn't accept a parse string):

```
    client = boto3.client(
        service_name='logs',
        region_name=aws_region,
        aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
        aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key
    )

    rows = []
    next_token = {}
    while True:
        response = client.filter_log_events(
            logGroupName=log_group_name,
            logStreamNames=list_log_stream,
            startTime=start_time,
            endTime=end_time,
            filterPattern=filter_pattern,
            **next_token
        )

        rows += [item for item in
                 [str(parse_event(event)) for event in response['events']]
                 if item != 'None']

        if 'nextToken' not in response:
            break
        next_token = {'nextToken': response['nextToken']}
```